# can a python dictionary replace only what it finds?

Tags: python, dictionary

The following works fine:

```
line = "Hello %(firstname)s %(lastname)s, how are you?"
print line % dict (firstname = "Mike", lastname="Kane")
```

and prints:

> Hello Mike Kane, how are you?

But if I don't have a value for `lastname`, I still want this to work:

```
line = "Hello %(firstname)s %(lastname)s, how are you?"
print line % dict (firstname = "Mike")
```

I want it to just ignore the lastname key and print:

> Hello Mike , how are you?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

line = "Hello %(firstname)s %(lastname)s, how are you?"
print line % defaultdict(str, firstname = "Mike")
```

Explanation: the first argument to the `defaultdict` initializer must be a callable that returns the default value. `str` is callable that returns an empty string (try `str()`).

Comment: This isn't a flexible technique because the factory function doesn't take an argument.  If you use \_\_missing\_\_ instead, there are many options for what can be returned.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: true, but that's not in the OP's specs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use make a subclass of dictionary that supplies defaults for missing values:

```
>>> class Dict(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
            # supply a default value for a given key
            return key


>>> d = Dict(firstname = 'Mike')
>>> print "Hello %(firstname)s %(lastname)s, how are you?" % d
Hello Mike lastname, how are you?
```

The techniques gives you complete control over what is returned.  Here are some variants:

```
return '--missing--'       returns a default string
return key.upper()         highlight the missing key
return ''                  return an empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return ""
print("Hello %(firstname)s %(lastname)s, how are you?"
      % MyDict(firstname = "Mike"))
```

prints

```
Hello Mike , how are you?
```